# ¿Cómo editar la wiki de una etiqueta?

Tags: soporte, etiquetas, ediciones, wiki-de-etiqueta

Estoy intentando añadir una descripción a la etiqueta [bash](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) y no puedo.

Cuando voy a https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info no veo ningún enlace para editar su contenido, pese a que en la [lista de etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags) me sale la opción "editar" que enlaza a https://es.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/49. En lugar de aterrizar en este lugar, la web está redirigida a la información de la etiqueta.

Lo que esperaría es encontrar el botón "Proponer informacion de Etiqueta" que sí sale por ejemplo en Meta para la [etiqueta [tag:interfaz]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/interfaz/info) que no tiene contenido.

¿Es esto un bug? Nótese que sucede con todas las etiquetas que no tienes descripción, mientras que cualquier otra que sí tenga puede editarse sin problema (por ejemplo [editar la etiqueta c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/50)).

Comment: hay muchas etiquetas que tienen descripción, incluso _[bash](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info)_ ya tiene una.

Comment: Duplicado de http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96/edici%C3%B3n-de-wikis-de-las-etiquetas

Comment: @dwarandae tienes razón, gracias.